# Change image channel ordering from channel first to last

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change the ordering of this numpy images array to channel_last
training_data : (2387, 1, 350, 350) to (2387,350,350,1)
validation_data : (298, 1, 350, 350) to (298, 350, 350, 1)
testing_data : (301, 1, 350, 350) to (301, 350, 350, 1)

I tried this but it is not working

```
np.rollaxis(training_data,0,3).shape
np.rollaxis(validation_data,0,3).shape
np.rollaxis(testing_data,0,3).shape
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need the `np.transpose` method like this:

```
training_data = np.transpose(training_data, (0,2,3,1))
```

The same can be done for the other ones

Answer (score 1):

If the axis you are moving has length `1` a simple reshape will do:

```
a = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 1, 3, 4)

# Three different methods:
b1 = a.reshape(2, 3, 4, 1)
b2 = np.moveaxis(a, 1, 3)
b3 = a.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)

# All give the same result:
np.all(b1 == b2) and np.all(b2 == b3)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
np.rollaxis(array_here,axis_to_roll,to_where)
```

For your case you want to roll axis 0 to last position (beyond 3) so you have to put to_where as 4 (beyond 3).

This will work(personally tested):

```
np.rollaxis(train_data,0,4)
```